# How to get response payload using Coldfusion?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11, coldfusion-2016

I trying to get a response payload, that's returns from developer tools->network->response. Could you please share how to do it?

**JSON**

```
{"COLUMNS":["AGE"],"DATA":[[24]]}
```

**Response Payload**

[image: Image of response payload]

Comment: Please provide some code for context.  How/where are you trying to use the response?

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't say, I shall assume your question is about a page generated by ColdFusion. To get the response in Developer Tools, follow these steps:

1. Open the page in the browser.
2. Press F12 on the keyboard to open Developer Tools.
3. Press F5 on the keyboard, refreshing the page and ensuring that the request details appear in Developer Tools.
4. In Developer Tools, click on the name of the ColdFusion file, then on
   the Response tab.